# How to count result rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame. I want to count the number of rows which is satisfied the condition.

data have 800 rows; `data[data['cond'] == 1]` return frame with 343 rows. I need to store number of rows in a variable. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, I think you can just do:

```
a = len(data[data['cond'] == 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
a = data[data['cond'] == 1].shape[0]
```

I try timeings and it seems both options are the same in large `df` (length `60k`):

```
In [1399]: %timeit data[data['fld1'] == 1].shape[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.9 ms per loop

In [1400]: %timeit len(data[data['fld1'] == 1])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.91 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
x = sum(data['cond'] == 1)
```

(data['cond']==1) creates a Series object filled with boolean values and sum treats True as 1 and False as 0.

```
x = len(data[data['cond'] == 1])
```

will also do the trick, and might be more readable, but I believe it will create an intermediate slice of 'data'.